# grep entire(not exact) match in R

Tags: regex, r

I would like to match for the entire word. If you see below, I want the grep for "is" to show only 4 in the output since only "this is a line", contains the entire word "is"

I also tried searching using ^ and $ as shown below, but I'm looking for a string which exactly matches "is". It may contains other words also, as long as the word "is" is present as a separate word

```
> lines = c("this","this","this","this is a line")
> grep("is",lines)
[1] 1 2 3 4
> grep("^is$",lines)
integer(0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to place [**word boundaries**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) around your pattern.

```
grep('\\bis\\b', lines)
```

**Note:** The `^` anchor asserts that the regular expression engine's current position in the string is the beginning of the string and `$` asserts the position at the end of the string. So, by implementing both anchors, you're telling the engine that the whole string should match.

Comment: thanks. But if my search key is a variable, say mykey = "is", how do I then use the same?

Comment: using paste to concatenate each of the individual components worked for me like grep(paste0("\\b",mykey,"\\b"), lines)
Thanks for helping me.